# Por qué lo concatena?

Tags: javascript

*Por qué en mi código lo **esta concatenando en vez de sumarlo**, si se supone que la función `isNaN`, lanzaría un error en caso de que **NO fueran números**? entonces en ese caso para que usar `isNaN`, y no usar directamente `parseInt` o `parseFloat`* ?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    c.addEventListener("click", suma);

    function suma() {

        try {
            var a = prompt('Primer número');
            var b = prompt('Segundo número');
            if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) throw "Ingresa un número";
            alert('El resultado es: ' + (a + b));
        } catch (k) {
            alert(k);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="c" type="button" value="Calculame">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por que el resultado de la función prompt() es un string y en javascript el signo `+` se usa para sumar(en el caso de numeros) y también se usa para concatenar(en el caso de strings). Utiliza la función [Number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/4987172)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    c.addEventListener("click", suma);

    function suma() {

        try {
            var a = prompt('Primer número');
            var b = prompt('Segundo número');
            if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) throw "Ingresa un número";
            alert('El resultado es: ' + (Number(a) + Number(b)));
        } catch (k) {
            alert(k);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="c" type="button" value="Calculame">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por qué Number() ?

Comment: Number convierte un string a su equivalente en numero y es una función nativa muy simple en js. Ya se comprobó que la cadena contiene un numero, ahora hay que convertirlo a numero, para poder realiza operaciones con el.

Comment: y parseInt o Float?

Comment: Number convierte el parámetro obtenido a su equivalente en número, ya sea entero o flotante, parseInt y parseFloat necesitan los valores especificos a si mismos. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4564158/4987172) hay una pregunta en donde se pueden ver las diferencias